# What does the update method return in Mongotemplate?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I want to know what is the result returned by update method in mongoTemplate.

Ex. `mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, entityClass);`

It returns us a WriteResult object.What are its content in case the update is successful/fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in MongoTemplate Documentation:

> public com.mongodb.WriteResult updateFirst(Query query,
>                                              Update update,
>                                              Class entityClass)
>   Description copied from interface: MongoOperations
>   Updates the first object that is found in the collection of the entity class that matches the query document with the provided update document.
>   Specified by:
>   updateFirst in interface MongoOperations
>   Parameters:
>   query - the query document that specifies the criteria used to select a record to be updated
>   update - the update document that contains the updated object or $ operators to manipulate the existing object.
>   entityClass - class that determines the collection to use
>   Returns:
>   the WriteResult which lets you access the results of the previous write.

The results can be found using:
getN() for Success and getError() for failure from WriteResult returned.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#updateFirst-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update-java.lang.Class-

https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.6/com/mongodb/WriteResult.html

Comment: intresting that the docs referred don't mention wasAcknowledged() function which came to my rescue ( maybe a version issue ).
wasAcknowledged() returns true if the update request was acknowledge else returns false.

Answer (score 2):

For all fellow readers, here's a bit more info ~

Mongo's `mongoTemplate.updateFirst` and many other methods return the abstract `UpdateResult` class, ie. an instance of `AcknowledgedUpdateResult` & `UnacknowledgedUpdateResult`

The info which you can get from this instance:

- `long matchedCount`
- `long modifiedCount`
- `BsonValue upsertedId` *# document id as string*

You can call

- `wasAcknowledged()`
- `isModifiedCountAvailable()`
- `getMatchedCount()`
- `getUpsertedId()`

Note that `isModifiedCountAvailable()` is deprecated.

By executing the above method (and many other similar methods within `com.mongodb.client.result`) you ***cannot*** get the full document/model.

The best you can do, is check whether the update was successful, check the modified count, and/or execute another query to find the full document by id, if needed.

Hoping this will help others, considering the above info didn't prove much useful for me imho.

Answer (score 0):

**The result returned by updateFirst method is a com.mongodb.WriteResult object and the below methods can be used to find the update is successful or failed.**

> com.mongodb.WriteResult: 
>   This class lets you access the results of the
>   previous write **(update or insert)**.

**What are its content in case the update is successful/fails ?**

**getN():**

If success, returns the number of records updated in the collection.

**getError():**

If failure, returns the error message.

You can lookat the API [here](https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.6/com/mongodb/WriteResult.html)
https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.6/com/mongodb/WriteResult.html